# Updating related row in another table cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, relationship, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to update a row in an associated table after a saving data in the current table. Say I have two tables, Listings and Queues. Queues has a foreign key of listing_id. So I've succesfully saved a new queue, which of course also includes the id of a listing, how can also update the status field of the Listing on the Listings table, say from from "paused" to "queued"?

See how my code looks like

```
$queue = $this->Queues->newEntity();
$queue->listing_id = $this->request->data['id'];
$queue->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

if ($this->Queues->save($queue)) {      

    $this->response->body("success");

    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'ListingsController','action' => 'changeStatus', $this->request->data['id'], "queued"));

}
```

Associations

Listings Table

```
    $this->table('listings');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Queues Table

```
    $this->table('queues');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Listings', [
        'foreignKey' => 'listing_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Comment: Trying starting with the documentation on [saving associated data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations).

Comment: Please state your model associations first. You could simply load the associations while creating `newEntity()` and save both the model data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Believe me when I say I've read through that documentation over and over. Just can't figure it out. I'm a bit new to the framework, I know it'll end up being something simple I'm missing. Please what do you mean by model associations, Let me update the question with what I think you mean. Thanks

Comment: What is the $queues Object looking like? If it is build correctly, cake would automatically take care of updating associations.

Comment: the Queues table only has 3 fields: id, user_id, listing_id

Comment: But are they also in the structure that is demanded by orm? As stated in the link of @ drmonkeyninja in Saving BelongsTo Associations

Comment: I'm lost please

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick: $this->loadModel('Listings');

And then from there I could do a ->newEntity(), ->patchEntity() and/or ->save() on the Listings object using a WHERE clause on the query, like I would in the Listings controller.

E.g:

```
$this->loadModel('Listings');
$listing = $this->Listings->get($id);
$listing->status = "completed";
$this->Listings->save($listing);
```

Quite simple.

Comment: This sounds FAR more complicated and error-prone than it should need to be.

Comment: l0l, I wasn't actually specific. The statement on the first line was actually what I was missing. That's how you load and use models from other models in cakephp3

Comment: Edited my answer to state what I meant

Comment: While this will work just fine, there are other, theoretically better, ways to do it. For example, you might include the updated listing information in the `$queue` object, and then saving that will also update the listing record. This is what @drmonkeyninja and @tolga were getting at.

Another option would be to create an event listener that would fire whenever a queue is saved, and update the listing as required. This is more complicated, but might be better if you have multiple places in your code that queues need to be saved, as the listing update code is then in just one spot.